# Calculate symbolic square root of expression (with parameters) in python?

Tags: python, math, symbolic-math

Is it possible to calculate a square root of an expression in python ? 
For example , the square root of: `(a^4 - 8a^2 -16a + 16)`?

Of course the result will be with `a`, not a numeric value.
I read about math.sqrt() and tried doing this , but pycharm insisted that i would assign a value into a .

```
import math
a = 16
b = math.sqrt(a**4 - 8*(a**2) -16*a +16 )
print b
```

this code works , but I do not want to assign into a , I want an expression as a result .

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Have you tried doing this yourself yet?

Comment: Have you tried [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)?

Comment: @matsjoyce: so why does the user need to try sympy to execute a mathematical expression? Python can do this directly without any help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters He wants it with `a` as a variable in the answer, not a numerical value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I read about math.sqrt and tried doing this , but pycharm insisted that i would assign a value into a .

Comment: @matsjoyce: what, like a function?

Comment: @Noam: why not elaborate on that then in your question? What larger problem are you trying to solve here? What do you need this for?

Comment: @matsjoyce: my point is more that this question is *too vague* and open to multiple interpretations, widely differing.

Comment: I think your question might be better phrased "Is it possible to simplify an algebraic expression with Python?" since that sounds like what you want to do.

Comment: Might help if you provide an example of what you *expect the output to be*.

Comment: ok I should have wrote that . sorry . well I need this because I like programming and hate doing my math homework .... lol

Comment: @MartijnPieters He seems to want symbolic manipulation, e.g. `sqrt(a^2+8a+4) = a + 2`. I agree about being broad, though.

Comment: @matsjoyce: again, that's open to interpretation.  A good question is clearer than this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry .  I edited this question , I hope it is better now

Comment: @Noam See http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-5-Sympy.ipynb#Sympy---Symbolic-algebra-in-Python, although your quaternary doesn't seem to simplify easily.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I'm assuming that what you want is to take an algebraic expression, and simplify it by factoring parts of it. Is that right?

You could use [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for this general class of question, but I note that (to the best of my knowledge) your example doesn't have a simpler answer! Here's an example where it can work:

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol, factor
>>> a = Symbol("a")
>>> factor(a**4 - 8*a**3 + 20*a**2 - 16*a + 4)
(a**2 - 4*a + 2)**2
```

However, I don't think your example has any factors. Is it actually an instance of a problem you need to solve, or just a general example of the shape of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Python has a lot of batteries inside, however its huge standard library does  not contain any symbolic algebraic module.
Thus, if you want to do symbolic calculations, you have to use external modules, such as [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) (as already suggested), or mathematical systems, such as [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/).

What you can do in "standard" Python is to define a function which takes `a` as a parameter and that returns the corresponding value of your expression:

```
def f(a):
    import math
    return math.sqrt(a**4 - 8*(a**2) -16*a +16)
```

Depending on your application, this could be enough.